# How to create function inside class in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the problem in the below code?

```
class c{
   constructor() {
       var a =100;
   }
   function r(){
      console.log(this);
   }
}
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` In the above code.

If we remove the **function** keyword then no error.

I tried above code in google chrome developer console.

What is the concept behind this?

Comment: That's invalid syntax for classes. Consider reading up on how to write methods in JS classes?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-classes-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your using class based and has methods, not functions. To define a method you can do like so:

```
class c{
   constructor() {
       var a =100;
   }
    r(){
      console.log(this);
   }
}
```

If you want to be able to define functions inside  you'll need to transform it to functional first:

```
function Test() {
  function test() {
    // This now works
  }
}

test1=new Test()
```

Comment: The last code block might need some more explanation, since you can't call `test1.test()`. You might want to add how you use the `test` function, and when this way of writing it is useful.

Comment: I got the difference, Thanks @shashi

Answer (score 5):

The JavaScript way of defining a class is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```
class c {
   constructor() {
       var a = 100;
   }
   r() {
       console.log(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: why arrow functions are still not working?

Comment: @avi it depends on how you implement it - the other answer shows a way to define it as an arrow function

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, **global functions** can only be defined in the global context. If you want to define a class-related function, you should either define it as a class method or as an arrow function:

```
function globalFn() {
  // this is a global function
  // it is parsed immediately and can be used everywhere
}

class c {
  innerMethod() {
    // this is an inner method that belongs to class c
    // you can call it with: c.innerMethod();
  }

  innerArrowFunction = () => {
    // this is an inner arrow function that belongs to class c
    // you can call it with: c.innerArrowFunction();
  }
}
```

See also:

- [JavaScript function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)
- [Class body and method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score -1):

proper syntax

```
class c{
   constructor() {
       var a =100;
   }
    r = () => {
      console.log(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that [class field declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are currently still a stage 3 proposal and not yet a standard. One should also be aware of the [differences between a normal instance method deceleration and an instance field arrow declaration](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1).